# Escape Character issues

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2008, escaping, odbc

I generally understand the idea behind escaping quotes using backslashes and alternatively using backslashes to escape so that you can have backslashes in your strings and so forth, but I've run in to a problem trying to pass a query through `odbc_exec()` and using a table-valued function and I just cannot seem to get it to stop giving me

```
SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '0000005'.
```

This is what it looks like when I hard code the variables:

```
$query = 'SELECT '.$csvCriteria.", googStep, Segment, PrevailingDirection FROM jSelectorCSVCreator('1','1','northbound','0006009','00000050370A2P000004','00060041270B2P000070','1')";
```

This works fine. Note that $csvCriteria hasn't given me any problems. This is what I want it to look like:

```
$query = 'SELECT '.$csvCriteria.", googStep, Segment, PrevailingDirection FROM jSelectorCSVCreator('".$stepNum."', '".$segMarker."', '".$prevDirection."', '".$rdNoA."', '".$re_1."', '".$re_2."', '".$directionA."')";
```

However I keep getting errors around $re_1 and $re_2 (the error I've put in at the top of this).

I've tried multiple variations of what I think may work, such as:

```
$query = 'SELECT '.$csvCriteria.", googStep, Segment, PrevailingDirection FROM jSelectorCSVCreator('".$stepNum."','".$segMarker."','".$prevDirection."','".$rdNoA.'\',\''.$re_1.'\',\'00060091100B1P000030\',\'1\')';
```

But I am neither expertly proficient at this, nor do I know if I'm missing something blatantly obvious. Just absolutely stuck and need a hand!

Comment: Please echo out `$query`, you'll probably see where the issue is.

Comment: Hi Dave, I have echoed $query, and I have had other people have a look at the result with me (who know what they're doing much more so than me) and we still can't see why it's giving me this error.

Comment: `SELECT REId rePosition reSpeedLimit reBearing RE RdNo LkNo reLat reLon  googStep  Segment  PrevailingDirection FROM jSelectorCSVCreator(1 1  Westbound  "0000005'  '0000005370A2P00003'  '0000005370A2P00009' '1')  
`

Answer (score 1):

I can not reproduce your error:

The SQL in question is:

```
SELECT csvcriteria, 
       googstep, 
       segment, 
       prevailingdirection 
FROM   jselectorcsvcreator('1', '1', 'northbound', '0006009', 
'00000050370A2P000004', '00060041270B2P000070', '1');
```

Placing the data in variables such as:

```
$csvCriteria   = 'csvCriteria';
$stepNum       = 1;
$segMarker     = 1;
$prevDirection = 'northbound';
$rdNoA         = '0006009';
$re_1          = '00000050370A2P000004';
$re_2          = '00060041270B2P000070';
$directionA    = 1;
```

Using the first line of code, which works and using the one that doesn't work both return the exact same thing:

```
$correct = 'SELECT ' . $csvCriteria . ", googStep, Segment, PrevailingDirection FROM jSelectorCSVCreator('1','1','northbound','0006009','00000050370A2P000004','00060041270B2P000070','1')";
$query   = 'SELECT ' . $csvCriteria . ", googStep, Segment, PrevailingDirection FROM jSelectorCSVCreator('" . $stepNum . "','" . $segMarker . "','" . $prevDirection . "','" . $rdNoA . "','" . $re_1 . "','" . $re_2 . "','" . $directionA . "')";

echo $correct . "\n";
echo $query . "\n";

var_dump($correct === $query);
```

The response is ([CodePad](http://codepad.org/egN0KXMx)):

```
SELECT csvCriteria, googStep, Segment, PrevailingDirection FROM jSelectorCSVCreator('1','1','northbound','0006009','00000050370A2P000004','00060041270B2P000070','1')
SELECT csvCriteria, googStep, Segment, PrevailingDirection FROM jSelectorCSVCreator('1','1','northbound','0006009','00000050370A2P000004','00060041270B2P000070','1')
bool(true)
```

My guess is that `$csvCriteria` or any of the variables at hand have errors.

I would highly recommend looking at the echoed query of `$query` in an [SQL Formatter](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm) (Select MS ACCESS)

Comment: It would appear I was using a function called stripslashes() further up in my code. Apparently this doesn't actually get rid of the backslashes as I would have assumed it would. Instead I've just ended up using str_replace() and it's working fine. Without your confirmation that nothing was wrong I wouldn't have been able to work that. Thanks Dave!

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = 'SELECT '.$csvCriteria.", .....
```

should be

```
$query = 'SELECT '.$csvCriteria.', ......
```

Comment: Any chance you could show me what you think the entire line should look like? I believe I went that route already and it didn't fix anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$query = "SELECT $csvCriteria, googStep, Segment, PrevailingDirection FROM jSelectorCSVCreator('$stepNum','$segMarker','$prevDirection','$rdNoA','$re_1','00060091100B1P000030','1')";
```

This is much simpler without need of all the escapes.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out I was attempting to pass a string that looked like this "0000000\000X00X0\0000000" and it wasn't working so well. I decided to use stripslashes() so I could pass the variable more easily and work with it once it was in SQL. Turns out stripslashes() doesn't work like that. I used str_replace() instead and it now works fine.